# Get last modifications from GIT with Visuyal Studio

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I tried many procedures to update local branch like SVN Update but impossible to have the good result.

Here is the problem :

I created 2 new branches. In the first branch, I added a new class in a project (test project to write GIT procedure) and commit. Then I made a pull request and validate it to update master (with branch deletion).

My colleague use the second branch and add a new class, but he like to update his repo with last master version (like SVN Update).

How can I do that ?

I tried these manipulations :
- double clic on local master and Pull button to update local master, and merge local master to local branch : don't works
- on local branch, pull button but error message (some modifications have not been saved...)
- Sync button : don't works

To resume, if a developper start to develop on a branch and after many days, want to get the last version of remote master to merge on his lacal branch, how can he do ?

Thanks

Comment: So, the master updated, and your colleague want to merge the master to his second local branch?

Comment: Commit your changes before updating your local repository with changes from the remote.

Comment: I would like to use a new class commited in master without commit my changes. Is it possible ?